# Regular Expressions & Minimum DFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Suppose that we have been given a regular expression $L$ and then we are asked to calculate the minimum number of states in the minimum sized DFA?
How can we go about solving such questions?

What I thought is that first we need to convert the given regular expression to The DFA and then minimise it.

> Is there any better way which can directly give the number of states or even the minimised DFA? The way I follow becomes sometimes very tough as it depends whether the expression at hand is an easy one or  a tough one. Is there some general algorithm or some lemma which might come in handy in order to answer such questions?

(This is supposed to be a reference question. Please include a general description of your method as well as a non-trivial example.)